# GooglePlayServicesClient and ConnectionCallbacks

Tags: android, google-play-services, locationlistener

Im init LocationClient and LocationRequest

```
locationClient = new LocationClient(context, this, this);
request = LocationRequest.create();
        request.setInterval(MIN_TIME);
        request.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);
        request.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        request.setFastestInterval(FAST_INTERVAL_CEILING_IN_MILLISECONDS);
```

connect to GooglePlayServices

```
locationClient.connect();
```

and request location updates when execute callback method

```
@Override
public void onConnected(final Bundle bundle)
{
  locationClient.requestLocationUpdates(request, this);//this exception point
}
```

But throws exception

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not connected. Call connect() and wait for    onConnected() to be called.    
            at com.google.android.gms.internal.k.B(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.internal.bh.a(Unknown Source)   
            at com.google.android.gms.internal.bh$c.B(Unknown Source)   
            at com.google.android.gms.internal.bg.requestLocationUpdates(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.internal.bh.requestLocationUpdates(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.internal.bh.requestLocationUpdates(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.location.LocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(Unknown Source)    
            at ru.etransport.locationlib.LocationListenerGPs.onConnected(LocationListenerGPs.java:45)
```

**upd:** I use **isGooglePlayServicesAvailable** before connecting

Comment: Hi, did you manage it? I'm currently facing the same problem ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use isGooglePlayServicesAvailable, it checks the availability of the service.

Comment: I'm use before connecting

Answer (score 0):

Are you instantiating **GoogleApiClient** anywhere?  Like:

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(Wearable.API)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();
```